# How to take value from one cell and add to list over multiple excel files

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I'm trying to select the same cell from multiple excel files and add them to a list, but I keep getting double of the same number. How do I solve this? 
I'm using xlrd, os, and numpy libraries to do this.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Users/Isaac/Experiment"):
   xlsfiles = [_ for _ in files if _.endswith('xlsx')]
   my_matrix = []
   my_matrix_2 = []
   for xlsfile in xlsfiles:
      workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(root,xlsfile))
      worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
      for col in range(worksheet.ncols):
          my_matrix_2.append(worksheet.cell_value(4,1))
   print my_matrix_2
```

What I get as as a result is 
[4.0, 4.0, 40.0, 40.0, 44.0, 44.0, 48.0, 48.0, 52.0, 52.0, 56.0, 56.0, 60.0,           60.0, 64.0, 64.0, 68.0, 68.0, 72.0, 72.0, 76.0, 76.0, 8.0, 8.0, 80.0, 80.0, 84.0, 84.0, 88.0, 88.0, 92.0, 92.0, 96.0, 96.0, 100.0, 100.0, 12.0, 12.0, 16.0, 16.0, 20.0, 20.0, 24.0, 24.0, 28.0, 28.0, 32.0, 32.0, 36.0, 36.0]

Comment: Is it `EXCEL VBA` language?

Comment: Please add tags for the language you are coding in. Looks like Python. If so, also edit your question and specify the libraries you are using.

Comment: what is nCols? 
Perhaps you are executing that statement multiple times
Why do you even need that for loop of nCols
remove it and try

Comment: ncols is what i've been using to get data out of the excel file using the xlrd module

Comment: Are you looking to only grab cell `cell_value(4,1)`? If so, you may not really want to loop through the number of columns in each file.

Comment: Thank you Abdou! I just removed loop going through each columns in each file and fixed the indent o the append line and it worked

Comment: It does look like the `my_matrix_2` variable is being overwritten every time you loop through the files. Is that something desired?